# AWS IAM | Cannot Assume Role created on the same "session" (InvalidInputException)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-iam, roles, assume-role

This has happened to me on multiple occasions and I can't for the life of me figure out why. Examples:

- Boto3 script: If I create a role and then try to assume it i will get an error. BUT if the role is already created the service can assume it fine.
- Ansible playbook: If I run a playbook which first creates the roles and then I try to assign them, i will get an error. BUT if i first run a different playbook and then the one that assigns the roles, everything is fine.

I have tried waiting to make sure the role is created, but i still got the error. The error is:

```
"An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreateCrawler operation: Service is unable to assume role arn:aws:iam::<acc_id>:role/GlueReadS3. Please verify role's TrustPolicy"
```

The weird thing is, the same role can be assumed by CloudFormation just fine.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "glue.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }]
}
```

I should mention that the boto3 error also returned the Role ARN (so I'm assuming that it was created) and also that I made a `get_role` beforehand to get the ARN it also did not work

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: This problem is not bounded by code, hence the examples.

The process is:
Build the assume-role-document as shown above >

Create the role >

Add/Attach policies >

Try to link a resource and the role

Comment: *"so I'm assuming that it was created"*  Maybe, but more likely, that's not actually proven from this error message.  You could potentially confirm that by trying a nonexistent role.  This sounds like it could an internal replication delay that might resolve itself with sleep & retry.

Comment: I have tried [waiters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#waiters) and even sleeping for x amounts of seconds....no dice :/  Still, I am doing a `get_role` call before assigning it and it returns all the correct info. When trying to `get` a non-existing role you get `An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the GetRole operation: The role with name awd cannot be found.` (which is not what I am getting)

Comment: The problem looks like an issue with the trust relationship in the role you are creating via boto3. Can you check the trust relationship of the role created by the script and the one created manually beforehand?

Comment: The trust relationship has been checked  both by me and colleagues - it is fine. I have tried copy pasting the automatically generated one and it is the same down to the t. Plus, if the role already exists everything works fine

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can check the role in IAM, in my case, I thought I created a role like
`arn:aws:iam::<acc_id>:role/GlueReadS3`, but I then go to IAM and checked, it was actually `arn:aws:iam::<acc_id>:role/service-role/GlueReadS3`.